# Node gallery jcarousel

Tags: nodes

I am using node gallery for image gallery of 30 iamges, when i click the image in gallery it will takes to  nodegalleryJcariusel view and display all 30 images with previous and next arrows.

But when i filter the gallery with taxonomy ( will get 10 images) and when i click the image again jcarousel view showing all  30 images of gallery instead of 10 filetered images.

i am not drupal expert, have limited knowledge in PHP, please advice me how to do get only filtered images in jcarousel view.

thnx,
sri

Comment: Could you give us more information? Did you have the view saved? Did you ever get this to work?

If you think it's a module issue, try to recreate the problem in a fresh drupal install. If you can do that, post it to the module's issue queue so they can fix it for you and everyone else.